# redirecting script variable to log file without losing stderr

Tags: logs, io-redirection

When setting "set -x"  inside bash script, or if you run your script with `bash -x`, you will get all the arguments printed to the screen together with the stdout.

Is it possible to have stderr and stdout printed to screen but redirecting the `set -x` output to the log file without having it printed to the screen?

The idea is to have all the info I can get inside the log, but only print regular stdout and stderr to the screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
user1@mac1:~/tmp$ cat t1.sh
exec 4>shell.log
BASH_XTRACEFD=4

set -x
echo abc
cat ffff

user1@mac1:~/tmp$ bash t1.sh
abc
cat: ffff: No such file or directory
user1@mac1:~/tmp$ cat shell.log
+ echo abc
+ cat ffff
user1@mac1:~/tmp$
```

Comment: is it possible to do this also in bash version that does not support BASH_XTRACEFD ? i mean is there any other way to overcome this when BASH_XTRACEFD is not available?

Comment: why don't you try @PSkocik 's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The `set -x` output goes to `stderr`. What you need to do is redirect `stderr`, e.g.:

```
sh -x your_script.sh 2> debug_info.txt
```

If you want to distinguish the `stderr` output due to `set -x` from normal `stderr` output , you can utilize the fact that `set -x` output is prefixed with `$PS4`, which defaults to `+`.

```
bash -x your_script.bash 2> \
\
    >(tee >/dev/null \
           >(grep    '^\+ ' > set_x_output.txt)\
           >(grep -v '^\+ ' > rest_of_sdterr.txt)\
      )
```

If some of your normal `stderr` output begins with `+`, you can change the default prefix by changing `PS4`.

Comment: like i wrote i dont want to loose stderr not printed to screen in case i have errors in my script.

Comment: This redirects the rest of stderr to `rest_of_sderr.txt` if you use `/dev/tty`, it'll go back to the terminal or you can do `bash -x your_script.bash 3>2 2> ...` and then replace `rest_of_stderr.txt` with `&3`.

Comment: X Tian's solution is more terse for bash.  This will work with a `sh` script too.

Answer (score 0):

i've manage to fix my redirection with this command:

- its also let me control exactly what i'm excluding.
- this is only for bash version older then 4.1 where 
  BASH_XTRACEFD is not valid.

`exec 2> >(tee -a $LOG_FULL_NAME 2>&1 | grep -v "^+ \|^++ ") 1>&2`